# Emacs "on-request" completion interface for writing a major mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a major mode for a language and I want to offer completion after '.', or following a keypress. Completions are determined by sending a request to a backgound process using `process-send-string` and `set-process-filter`. The returned list of completions is dependent on the background process parsing the current state of the file and being instructed to give completions at that particular point.

I have tried using the popular `autocomplete` package, but it is really not written with this use case in mind. This is partly because it offers automatic suggetions (i.e. without keypress), which is a nice feature that I don't need. The function that you offer it to call needs to be called synchronously, and emacs process control is asynchronous. I have coded something up along the lines of https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async, but it doesn't feel robust at all, and has been very fiddly to get it working.

I like the menus used in `autocomplete`, and would like to know what would fit best with my use-case, preferably while also looking nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait synchronously for a background process's output with `accept-process-output`.  You might like to take a look at `gud-gdb-completions` and `gud-gdb-run-command-fetch-lines` in a recent enough version of `gud.el`.

Comment: Thanks. I had a trawl through `gud.el`, and found the use of `accept-process-output`. It uses `completion-at-point`, which I understand is the standard emacs way of doing this, but I find it to be a bit limiting (not easy to see all completions, can't display documentation alongside each completion). Perhaps I could use `accept-process-output` with autocomplete to do things synchronously.

Comment: Yes, the gud code is for `completion-at-point` but the principles should be the same for auto-complete support.